# how to display the contiguous cells in a row

Tags: excel, vba, copy-paste

I got 5 table headers in `A1:E1`.  I want to display the contiguous cells data `(A2, B4, D5, E1, F3)` in cells `A2:E2`.  Pls help to do so.  My code is displayed below

```
Sub test()
    Dim copyRange As Range, cel As Range, pasteRange As Range, 
        erow As Long, ecolumn As Long
    Set copyRange = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A2, B4, D5, E1, F3")
    Set pasteRange = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A2")
    For Each cel In copyRange
            cel.Copy
            erow = ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 1).Row
            erow = Sheet2.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(0, 1).Row
            ecolumn = Sheet2.Cells(2, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Offset(0, 1).Row
            pasteRange.Cells(1, ecolumn).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
    Next
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
End Sub
```

Comment: What exactly is your question? Does your code not work? Does it error? If so, where and what is the error message? If it doesn't error, what does it do?

Comment: Also, since you just need the values, you can skip using the clipboard and set the ranges' values equal to eachother: `pasteRange.Cells(1,eColumn).Value = cel.value`.

Answer (score 1):

Simpler approach:

```
Sub test()
    Dim cel As Range, pasteRange As Range

    Set pasteRange = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A2")
    For Each cel In ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A2, B4, D5, E1, F3")
            pasteRange.Value = cel.Value
            Set pasteRange = pasteRange.Offset(0, 1)
    Next

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

@TimWilliams' answer is quick and easy, but I just thought to show you how to do this with an array as well:

```
Sub t2()
Dim copyRange As Range, cel As Range, pasteRange As Range
Set copyRange = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A2, B4, D5, E1, F3")
Set pasteRange = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A2")

Dim copyVals() As Variant
ReDim copyVals(0 To copyRange.Cells.Count)

Dim n As Long
n = 0
For Each cel In copyRange
    copyVals(n) = cel.Value
    n = n + 1
Next cel

Dim k As Long
For k = LBound(copyVals) To UBound(copyVals)
    pasteRange.Offset(k, 0).Value = copyVals(k)
Next k
End Sub
```